# How do I check the number of items the exploring dweller in wasteland is holding without manually counting?

Tags: fallout-shelter

There's is a maximum number of 100 items the exploring dweller can hold. So is there any indication when the character hits 100 items?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. To get the exact count, the only way to do it is by counting.

However, as loot drops approximately every hour, and the events like the NGD also have a chance of dropping items, a dweller will typically reach 100 items around 90-95 hours. So just recall the dweller around that time.

Comment: Just a quick update on this answer... as of patch 1.2, dwellers automatically start heading back to the vault without prompting after hitting 100 items, with a message in their log: "That's as much as I can carry. I better head back and show the Overseer what I found." The explore button is even grayed out... They can do nothing except return to the vault when at the 100 item limit.